# Get all y-values from each bin

Tags: c++, loops

My question is the following: I have plotted a graph from a text file with x and y values. The graph itself is log(y/x) vs x. Next, I define "bin number" and "bin width", i.e. I want to divide the x axis into several pieces of certain width and get all the corresponding y-values. Now I'm stuck on getting all the values in a certain range - I only get one value for every "bin width". Below is a section of the code (C++ + ROOT) - so if I print vx[0], vy[0], I get the first entry from the text file, but I would like the code to first check if the x value is in the first bin (from 0.3-0.9), and if so, print all the corresponding y values. Then check if the x value is in the second bin (0.9-1.5) and so on. Any suggestions on how to do that are very welcome! :)

```
Float_t xmin = 0.3; //x-range starts at 0.3
Float_t xmax = 60.;  //x-range ends at 60
const Int_t bins = 100; //the x range divided into 100 pieces
Float_t binW = (xmax-xmin)/(float)bins; // bin width ~0.6


Double_t xv[bins], yv[bins];
Double_t *xntuple = ntuple->GetVal(0); //1. column in txt file
Double_t *yntuple = ntuple->GetVal(1); //log(y/x)
Double_t xaxis, yaxis;


Float_t s = xmin;

for(Int_t i=0; i<bins; i++){
    yaxis = yntuple[i];
    yv[i] = yaxis;
    xv[i] = s;  
    s += binW;  //bin width ~0.6
  }
cout << xv[0] << " and " << yv[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question and problem, but why the custom type-aliases `Float_t` and `Double_t`? What's wrong with the actual standard types `float` and `double`?

Comment: What's ntuple? What data produces an incorrect answer? What would be the correct answer? If the bins are based on the x axis, why do you only use the y axis? And how do you have only two axes for a function which takes two variables?

Comment: Instead of keeping X and Y values in separate arrays, you should have something like `struct Point { double x; double y; };` and keep all your `Point`'s in a `std::vector<Point>`.

Comment: How many points are there? You will have real trouble iterating over an array if you don't know where to stop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your constraints are with ROOT, but you can do something like this: make vectors for each bin; then iterate through all your data and check if the X value is in the current bin's range. If not, go to the next bin.

Something like this:

```
// Bins
std::vector<std::vector<Double_T>> vx, vy;
vx.resize(bins);
vy.resize(bins);

Float_T currentBinStart = xmin;
int currentBinNr = 0;

for (Int_T i = 0; i < numberOfValues; ++i) {
   // Check if value is in range
   if (xntuple[i] > currentBinStart+binWidth) {
      // No => go to next bin
      currentBinStart += binWidth;
      currentBinNr++;
   }
   vx[currentBinNr].push_back(xntuple[i]);
   vy[currentBinNr].push_back(yntuple[i]);
}
```

Note: This assumes that the X-Values are sorted in ascending order!

Comment: I implemented your piece of code, but it gives me segmentation violation. The code looks like this now: I have the same first four rows and this is the same:
Double_t *xntuple = ntuple->GetVal(0); 
Double_t *yntuple = ntuple->GetVal(1);
but otherwise its the code you sent... I don't know what got wrong :S

Comment: Check if `currentBinNr` gets > bins. If so, you will access a bin that doesn't exist. This suggests that there's an error in your data... e.g. x values > xmin + bins*binWidth. Also, check that `numberOfValues` is correct. Generally, use a debugger and see what happens